# How to move resizableUIView from its corner in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I want to drag resizable UIView from its corner?
Like on desktop we Click the mouse button and hold on click and drag the mouse then a transparent view is visible like this.

I want this in my Project in iPhone. I want when the user touch and drag the finger one resizable transparent view will visible.

I have done so far on click on button the view is visible and that is resizable also. But it is not my solution, I want on touch on any iphone screen the resizable UIView will come.

Any Idea and suggestions would be highly welcome.

This is my code what I have done so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[imageVw addGestureRecognizer:tap];
tap.delegate=self;
pan=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
[pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[pan setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
[pan setDelegate:self];
count=0;
//    [pan minimumNumberOfTouches:1];
//    [pan maximumNumberOfTouches:2];
[imageVw addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}



-(void)handleTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

userResizableView = [[SPUserResizableView alloc] init];
userResizableView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h);
//UIView *content_View = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:userResizableView.bounds];
//[content_View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
imageVw1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:userResizableView.bounds];
//imageVw1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redacted2.jpg"];
imageVw1.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
imageVw1.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
imageVw1.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
imageVw1.alpha = 0.13;  // for opacity
userResizableView.contentView = imageVw1;
//[content_View addSubview:imageVw1];

//userResizableView.contentView = content_View;
userResizableView.delegate = self;
[userResizableView showEditingHandles];
currentlyEditingView = userResizableView;
lastEditedView = userResizableView;

// [self.view addSubview:userResizableView];
// [imageVw addSubview: dview];
[self.view addSubview: userResizableView];
[userResizableView release];

}

- (void)userResizableViewDidBeginEditing:(SPUserResizableView *)userResizableView1 {

 width  =   userResizableView.frame.size.width;
 height  =   userResizableView.frame.size.height;
 width1 = width;
 height1 = height;
 width = width + width;
 height = height + height;
[currentlyEditingView hideEditingHandles];
currentlyEditingView = userResizableView1;


}

- (void)userResizableViewDidEndEditing:(SPUserResizableView *)userResizableView1 {

lastEditedView = userResizableView1;
x1 = x;
y1 = y;
x =  userResizableView.frame.origin.x;
y = userResizableView.frame.origin.y;

}
```

Comment: Sir this is not I want. I have this demo. Please if you have any idea or suggestions please tell me.

Comment: try this https://github.com/bitmantra1/ResizeImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to declare two global variables

```
CGPoint startPoint;
BOOL _shouldResize;
```

Then you have to override two touch event methods in your view as given

1.TouchesBegan

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self superview]];

/*

 Here you have to check user tap to the corner of your view by using the method
 CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, touchPoint);

 Here the parameter rect should be the corner of your view

 if(!CGRectContainsPoint(CGRect rect, touchPoint)) { // Here user did not tap in your specific rect. so no need of resizing

    _shouldResize = NO;
    return;
 }

 */

_shouldResize = YES;

startPoint = touchPoint;

}
```

2.TouchesMoved

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if(!_shouldResize)
    return;

CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self superview]];

CGFloat displacementX = touchPoint.x - startPoint.x;
CGFloat displacementY = touchPoint.y - startPoint.y;

startPoint.x = touchPoint.x;
startPoint.y = touchPoint.y;

CGRect frame = [self frame];
frame.size.width += displacementX;
frame.size.height += displacementY;

[self setFrame:frame];

}
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self superview]];    // Super view not found

Comment: You have to implement this method in your view which has to be resized. not in viewcontroller or any other classes. To implement these methods, you have create new view class and its .m paste the codes, and create new instance of your new class instead of UIView ok?

Comment: Sir One more question can I start My view From Where I touch?  In my code I give UIView.frame = Cgrectmake(100,200,0,0);   instead of "self".  so my view start of (100,200,0,0); So now I want Where I touch Uiview start from there. Is it possible?

Comment: If you give width and height 0, 0 then there is no view will get appeared. What you have to do, you initialize your view with it's maximum size or with a minimum size (not 0,0 as width and height ok?)first and let the user to resize it by touch and move on its corners ok?

Comment: Yes there is no view when user touch and drag finger the view will appear and end where the user untouch the screen. And uiview start from where the user touch the screen.

Comment: I am not clear. What is actual requirement? Once user tap on the view, new view has to be created and resize the newly created view according to user swipe on the screen and destroy the view when user released the touch?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am also trying Sir what you provide me is very good. This is extra stuff. I need that code and you help me alooot. Now I know what to do. If you can help further than I will be very thankful to you once again.  Thanks For the Help....Thank Alooot.